# Association in rails 3 tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 tables:

```
Product           Purshase       Supplier
supplier_id      product_id        name
```

And this are related models:

```
class Purshase < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :product
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :supplier
    has_many :purshase
end

class Supplier < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :product
end
```

I'd like to show this way in my view: `purchase.product.supplier.name`

Comment: I assume that `Purshase` and `purshase` really are `Purchase` and `purchase`, correct?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show supplier name in this way(`purchase.product.supplier.name`) in your view then you should change your model association a bit like this

```
class Purshase < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :product
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :supplier
    has_many :purshases
end

class Supplier < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :products
end
```

Now you can get your supplier name by `purchase.product.supplier.name` in your view.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that a `belongs_to` relationship is used in the model which table contains the foreign key, and `has_many` relationship is in the other model, the one without any foreign key.

With this in mind you will need to change your `Supplier`/`Product` relationship: A `Supplier` `has_many` products and a `Product` `belongs_to` a supplier:

```
class Purchase < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
end

class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :supplier
  has_many :purchases
end

class Supplier < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :products
end
```

You can read more about associations in the [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, there is a situation that a product may have many suppliers and a supplier may have many products. 
I suggest you create a middle model called ProductSupplier like:

```
class ProductSupplier < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :supplier
  belongs_to :purchase
end
```

Add the has_many to both Product and Supplier.

Model Product:

```
has_many :product_suppliers, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :suppliers, :through => :product_suppliers
```

Model Supplier:

```
has_many :product_suppliers, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :products, :through => :product_suppliers
```

You can build a relationship between products and suppliers by creating the ProductSupplier records.